# Why Rin Okumura is so special as "son of satan", if there are other sons of satans on the side of humans like Mephisto?

Tags: blue-exorcist

In *Ao no Exorcist* season 1, they say they didn't kill Rin Okumura in spite of his being a son of Satan, because they wanted to raise him to defeat Satan. But Satan has other sons on the side of humans like Mephisto. And also Amaimon seems to be under the orders of Mephisto. Then, why do humans need Rin to defeat Satan?